# Bar chart with one continuous variable and two grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the two variables(humidity and temp) set as factors and the continuous(growth) as my y variable.
I keep entering the code in to show a bar chart with error bars but the code keeps coming back as

> ```
> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
> ```

Help?

```
sum1 <- summarySE(hw5data, measurevar = "growth", groupvars = c("temp", "humidity"), na.rm = TRUE)
sum1
temp humidity  N    growth      sd          se          ci
  15    25    10    45.69654    4.072518    1.2878433   2.913304
  20    25    10    23.67354    5.755927    1.8201841   4.117542
  25    25    10    34.77897    5.200555    1.6445600   3.720253
  15    50    10    44.26177    6.144309    1.9430012   4.395374
  20    50    10    26.07061    3.688428    1.1663833   2.638542
  25    50    10    34.49862    2.730160    0.8633525   1.95303


library(ggplot2)   
t <- ggplot(sum1, aes(x = temp, y = growth, fill = humidity)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = growth - se, ymax = growth + se), width = .2,
                  position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))
t + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds") + 
    theme_classic()
```

Comment: the error message seems to be saying that your `humidity` variable is not a factor type. check what you get from `typeof(sum1$humidity)` 

Edit: also check `temp`. if you share sample data, it will make it easier to help you

Comment: Along with that, try removing the `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Reds")` layer. If it works, then the problem is that `humidity` is continuous, while you've selected a discrete color palette.

Comment: I just edited the post to show the data, I am trying to get an multi bar chart with three bars representing the two humidity levels and three groups representing the temps. Any suggestions? both humidity and temp are factors with growth as a continuous

Comment: yeah, try `fill = factor(humidity)`

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your `temp` and `humidity` variables are factors:

```
sum1$humidity = as.factor(sum1$humidity)
sum1$temp = as.factor(sum1$temp)
```

Then it should work:

```
ggplot(sum1, aes(x = temp, y = growth, fill = humidity)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = growth - se, ymax = growth + se), width = .2,
                position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Data used:

```
sum1 = as.data.frame(cbind(temp = c(15,20,25,15,20,25),
                           humidity = c(25,25,25,50,50,50),
                           growth = c(45.69654,23.67354,34.77897,44.26177,26.07061,34.49862),
                           se = c(1.2878433 ,1.8201841,1.6445600 ,1.9430012,1.1663833 ,0.8633525)))
```